# Logging in Azure Functions with EF Core and DI

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

### My question is:

I'm relatively new to using IoC containers and logging mechanisms in .NET Core.

How do I get logs written by my Entity Framework Core context to show up in my Azure Function log and in ApplicationInsights respectively.

### Background:

I have an Azure Function in which I use `.AddDbContext()` to register my DbContext for dependency injection:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyConnectionString");

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}
```

in Startup.cs.

The injected DbContext is then used in my data access layer library to do, well, database related stuff.
In some cases I want to explicitly log what's happening, but without having to implement a dedicated logger field or property in my DbContext class.

What I'm trying to do instead, is accessing the logging service which is registered with my DbContext through `.AddDbContext()` and  logging with an instance of ILogger which I'm getting by `var logger = contextInstance.GetService<ILogger<MyDbContext>>();`.

Now in theory I'd just go e.g. `logger.LogInformation("Something happened!");`. Since this does not throw any exceptions at runtime I guess it's kinda working.

I would now like to see **"Something happened!"** in my Function logs. Like this:
[image: azurefunction_log]

I am aware, that making these logs show up in Azure Function logs would cause all logs written by the context to pop up in my Function log as well. I'll worry about filtering later.. or maybe someone has a suggestion on this straight away?

Is it possible to make this work the way I want it to?

### On a side note:

If anyone has an opinion about this approach or could point me in a more best practice kind of way to achieve my logging in this scenario, I'd be happy to read any comments on that.

Comment: `logger.LogInformation("Something happened!");` is the correct way to add custom logs. Just to clarify, SQL logging in App Insights is logged under dependency tracking by default. Are you trying to log your EF data as traces instead so it shows up in the invocation details blade?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query

Comment: Haven't really tried this way of getting a ILogger before but I guess you see need to [add a filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#ilogger-and-iloggerfactory) for you code since almost everything is filtered out by default in `host.json`